# frame size of default keyboard's buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Is there a location to find out, or does anyone know the frame size of the basic button on apple's ipad keyboard?  and if possible, the other buttons like the return key etc?  I guess for now we can ignore that they are actually different sizes based on orientation...

Thanks

Comment: I don't know it. If you find some programmatic way then fine. Fix values don't work. Not only for localizing issues and because different keybord styles have different sizes of keys because of the different number of them. They even change with time. For Germany the keys are smaller with iOS 6 than they used to be before. Apple recently added the ÄÖÜäöü keys to the regular keyboard. More keys means less space for each of them.

Comment: As long as the measurements were at least decently close I think it would be OK

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the iOS Artwork Extract project? https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

It will let you pull out the exact images used in UIKit, then you can measure them yourself. :)